# Эффективна ли функция sleep()?

Tags: php, cron, sleep

Добрый день, хотим запустить скрипт, который рандомом на протяжении всего дня будет запускать различные функции.

Выполнение будет назначаться рандомно по времени от 0 до 24 часов в ожидании.
т.е. перед запуском скрипта будет команда:

```
sleep(rand(0, 60*60*24));  //  секунды*минуты*часы
```

т.к. команд на выполнение будет много, задумались об эффективности.

скажите будет ли эффективно использовать команду sleep или есть функция, которая меньше использует ресурсов?

возможно рандом вызывать через cron?

Comment: http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/admin/manage-planned-tasks-on-linux-with-the-command-at.html

Comment: Попробовал `php -r 'sleep(100);'` - в top тишина, CPU не кушает.

Comment: спасибо, но вопрос не в том, чтобы в кроне запускать в одно и то же время скрипт, а как сделать эффективно через крон  запуск в произвольное время в течение дня

Comment: "Попробовал php -r 'sleep(100);' - в top тишина, CPU не кушает" - сколько процессов параллельно запустили? больше сотни?

Comment: Так тем же rand запускать или нет скрипт по крону

Comment: А не проще ли сделать один единственный Cron скрипт (ежеминутный запуск) который будет генерировать время следующего события и каждую минуту проверять это? А когда наступит время Х, то выполнив всё необходимое сгенерировать новое время для события. Просто, на мой взгляд, вы пытаетесь чесать пяткой за ухом.

Comment: Хотя `sleep` не является builtin bash командой, она безусловно эффективна (потребляет минимум системных ресурсов). По сути, при ее вызове будет создан новый процесс, который тут же заснет. Немного утрируя -- несколько физических страниц памяти под таблицы виртуальной памяти процесса и очередной TCB в ядре.